# 'Incomplete type' of struct

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I have defined a particle class Particle in a .hpp file like this

```
#ifndef PARTICLE_HPP
#define PARTICLE_HPP
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <vector>

struct Particle
{
    Particle()
        : m_Position(0.0f)
        , m_Velocity(0.0f)
        , m_Color(1.0f)
        , m_fRotate(0.0f)
        , m_fAge(0.0f)
        , m_fLifeSpan(0.0f)
        , m_is_alive(false)
    {}
public:
    glm::vec3   m_Position; // Center point of particle
    glm::vec3   m_Velocity; // Current particle velocity
    glm::vec4   m_Color;    // Particle color
    GLfloat     m_fRotate;  // Rotate the particle the center
    GLfloat     m_fSize;    // Size of the particle
    GLfloat     m_fAge; 
    GLfloat     m_fLifeSpan; 
    bool        m_is_alive;

};
```

In another .cpp file i declared Particle in typedef namespace. What i am trying to do is instantiate Particle struct and push them in a vector. Since i have an empty constructor i believe instantiating with just Particle() should work. However, i could not do it because the compile argues there is 'incomplete type not allowed' error in the bolded line. 
**particles.push_back(Particle());**

```
#include "Particle.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include<vector>

typedef struct Particle Particle;
typedef std::vector<Particle> ParticleBuffer;
ParticleBuffer particles;


int main(){
    GLuint nr_particles = 100; 

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < nr_particles; ++i) {
        particles.push_back(Particle());
    }


}
```

---

**Solution**

Using typedef had omitted the real problem, and that is in

```
typedef struct Y Particle;
```

Here Y wasn't ever defined, as I believed it was pulling the definition from the header (.hpp) file, but for some reason Microsoft Visual Studio (which i was using to compile & build) didn't link the header file, but gave no errors. Instead, it just behaved like Y doesn't exist and if we look at the definition of 'incomplete type':

> Structure, union, or enumerations that have no definition

The error made sense now. 
The "workaround" solution was to use .h file instead of .hpp, so it would get linked. 
Also as @YSC pointed out in accepted answer, there is no need to use typedef, as the definition is correctly pulled from .h file it should give no errors.

Comment: `typedef struct Particle Particle;`: this is a C-ism. In C++, `struct x {...};` introduces the name `x` in the scope, no need to prefix it with `struct`.

Comment: Having just `struct Particle Particle` or `Particle Particle` gives "variable Particle is not a type name".

Comment: Please don't post answers as part of the question. If you'd like, you can answer your own question. This is accepted and encouraged. You can [edit] the _solution_ part out of your question and post it as an answer by replacing instances of _"I"_ into _"you"_ (yes, you should answer yourself as if you were talking to someone else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `typedef`s are not needed, not wanted, and break things. Indeed, `typedef struct Particle Particle;` is a C-ism. In C++, `struct x {...};` introduces the name `x` in the scope, no need to prefix it with `struct`.

Keep it simple:

```
#include <vector>

struct Particle { /* ... */ }; // in real life, this is defined in a separate file
std::vector<Particle> GlobalVariablesAreEvil;

int main()
{
    GlobalVariablesAreEvil.push_back(Particle{});
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27fa564b30a588f2).

Comment: @YSC can you fix your answer so that it would work if the definition of struct Particle was in a different file, but i declare it and use it in Particle.cpp?

Comment: s/`^struct Particle.*`/`#include "Particle.hpp"`/

Comment: If i define the struct Particle {...} in a .hpp file and only include "Particle.hpp" in my .cpp file i get "identifier Particle is undefined"

Comment: @wedran It should not happen. There's something else. Start from scratch. Define an empty `struct Particle` in an hpp file. Create a cpp file which **only** include the header file and define a variable of type `Particle`. Compile (no link, `-c` option of g++/clang++). From there, build up.

Comment: might be a Visual Studio error, compiles fine but building gives the same error. I will wait a bit more, if there is no new answers to this problem i will accept your answer